# Concatenate SqlDataReader to string in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

`reader.Read()` is sometimes false when looping and not all table rows are read. During this skipped state `reader.Read()` never becomes true. Waiting for it before iterating locks it up, of course. Is there a SQL connection status that will help mutex the loop? This happens 1 - 10% of the time during the loop.

** Answered: I was referencing the wrong sql column in my query. Adding reader.NextResult(); helped as well.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;

public string StringTableRows(string conn_str, int row_count)
{
    string s = "";

    Query query = new Query(); 

    for (int i = 1; i < row_count;)
    {
        // **Fix: I was referencing the wrong column.
        string dyn_query = query.RowQuery(ids[i]);

        try
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(conn_str);

            using (conn)
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(dyn_query, conn);

                using (cmd)
                {
                    cmd.Connection.Open();
                    SqlDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader();

                    using (reader)
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("Outside: " + i);

                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            for (int j = 0; j < reader.FieldCount; j++)
                            {
                                s = s + reader.GetString(0);
                                Debug.WriteLine("Inside: " + i);
                            }
                        }
                        // **Fix: This is the fix per answer.
                        reader.NextResult();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Failed query: " + dyn_query);
            Debug.WriteLine("Execute Exception: " + ex);
        }

        i++;
    }

    s = s.Insert(0,"<Tables>");
    s = s + "</Tables>";

    return s;
}
```

Comment: Do you have any kind of error in that Try/Catch? Remember GetString() could throw exceptions if data is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> reader. Read() is sometimes false when looping and not all table rows are read

That will only happen if the additional rows are in a separate resultset because the CommandText has multiple SELECT statements or calls a stored procedure with multiple SELECT statements.  In that case you have to call [SqlDataReader.NextResult()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.nextresult?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) before you call Read() again.